# Change textarea to tinyMCE Editor on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tinymce

I want to convert normal `textarea` to `tinyMCE` Editor on click of a button. The scenario is that i have two buttons on my page and two `textarea`from one button click one `jquery`function will be called and from other the second `jquery` button will be called, the function is called properly but the issue is that the normal `textarea`is not converted to `tinyMCE`Editor when a specific button is clicked. Please help to solve it below is my working code and one thing more after that there will be save button so on save button click the `tinyMCE`editor can be easily changed to normal `textarea`.

> index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
   function refreshdiv()
   {
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: 'load_tinymce.php',
    cache:false,
    success:function(html){

    var mainDiv = $('.attach_tiny_editor');
    mainDiv.empty();  
    $(mainDiv).prepend(html);

    },
    beforeSend: function(){

    },
    complete: function(){


    }  
    });
    }

    refreshdiv();



});

$(document).ready(function(){

$(document.body).on('click', '#refresh_1' ,function(e){
      refreshdiv();

      tinyMCE.init({mode : "none"});
      tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'txt12');
});

$(document.body).on('click', '#refresh_2' ,function(e){
      refreshdiv();
      tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'txt13');
});

});

</script>
<div class="attach_tiny_editor">

</div>
<input type="button" id="refresh_1" value="refresh"/>

<input type="button" id="refresh_2" value="refresh"/>
</body>
</html>
```

> load_tinymce.php

```
<div>
<textarea id="txt12">   </textarea>
<textarea id="txt13">   </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: cool and what is your problem with that code? we should run it and debug or call a fairy?

Comment: My textarea is not changing to tinyMCE editor on button click as you can see i have described above in my question.

Comment: did you manage to make tinymce working other way?

Comment: load_tinymce.php is a php file that is being called with ajax.I have given  an id to textarea.

Comment: Yes it is working, but i want it to work as i have written in my code.

Comment: have you tried to add a breakpoint i your click handlers and see what happens there and if they are called?

Comment: You aren't initializing tiny MCE editor anywhere in your posted code. Maybe you are trying form `load_tinymce.php` but hard to tell without seeing any relevant part

Comment: A. Wolff - The above code is working code .

Comment: mikus- Ihave tried the above code, the click event is called but conversion of textarea to tinyMCE does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the tinymce initialisation into the ajax success handler function in order to get executed. Otherwise the textarea is not there when needed.

**EDIT**: This will init only one editor!

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   function refreshdiv()
   {
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: 'load_tinymce.php',
    cache:false,
    success:function(html){

    var mainDiv = $('.attach_tiny_editor');
    mainDiv.empty();  
    $(mainDiv).prepend(html);

    tinymce.init({selector:'textarea#' + window.ed_id});

    },
    beforeSend: function(){

    },
    complete: function(){

    }  
    });
    }

    refreshdiv();
});

$(document.body).on('click', '#refresh_1' ,function(e){
      window.ed_id = 'txt12';
      refreshdiv();

      tinyMCE.init({mode : "none"});
      tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'txt12');
});

$(document.body).on('click', '#refresh_2' ,function(e){
      window.ed_id = 'txt13';          
      refreshdiv('txt13');
      tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'txt13');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have  to convert textarea in to tinyMCE editor on a button click, doing what you have said like tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'}); adding it in the success part makes both textbox change to tinyMCE on page load but i don't want that. Please give reply to my question.